# UnsupportedClassVersionError 1.7, works with 1.6 settings

Tags: java, eclipse, java-7, unsupported-class-version

I have EAR project, that consists of the following projects:

- TestRemoteEJB
- TestRemoteEJBClient
- TestRemoteWEB

Under each project I have set:

- Under Java Compiler I have set Compiler compliance level to 1.7
- Under Project Facets I have set Java to version 1.7

Also each project has JRE system library set to JRE7. If I use this settings, when I publish on JBoss AS7, I get UnsupportedClassVersionError. If I change the previously specified settings to 1.6 and JRE6, it successfully deploys. Why is that it works under 1.6, but not under 1.7 settings? I have the following setup on my computer.

For x86 I have:

- JRE6
- JRE7

For x64 I have:

- JDK 1.7 (which I found out is pointless as Eclipse uses its own compiler)
- JRE7

I am running Eclipse Indigo SR2 x86 edition, as I had some problems with x64 edition.

Comment: What is the Java version JBoss AS7 pointing to?

Comment: Ouch. I don't know how I missed that. I had an instance of a server set to 1.6, instead of 1.7. @thinksteep please answer it so I can accept it as right answer. By the way, is it really necesarry to have under Project Facets to 1.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure JBoss server pointing to correct Java version.

Comment: I am not clear on your comment related to project facets to 1.7? Can you provide little bit more details?

Comment: Under Project Facets there is property named Java and a drop down box where you can select different version (1.5, 1.6 or 1.7). Under details it says: "Adds support for writing applications using Java programming language.". I was wondering what exactly does it do, because I tried to set it to 1.6 and the project deploys without any problem.

Comment: When your env is 1.7, it is better to go with 1.7. I never used it, but based on your description, it seems IDE can understand syntax based on version (like try-with resource will be generated if enable 1.7 otherwise it won't). I may be wrong too